# How to position the reference fields line in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

TeX newbie. I want to position the reference fields line in scrlttr2 to where the "supplemental data" is usually displayed (in the top right hand corner, below the header).

I figured it would be as easy as

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{locvpos}}
\@setplength{refhpos}{\useplength{lochpos}}
\@setplength{refwidth}{\useplength{locwidth}}
\makeatother
```

but that doesn't work, the reference field line is rendered right at the top of the document. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm working on an invoice template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Vertical position:** Obviously `locvpos` has a value of 0 pt with your style, which is common for many letter styles. You could set it yourself or use `toaddrvpos` instead.
- **Horizontal position:** `refhpos` means a distance from the left paper edge, but `lochpos` from the right paper edge. So you would have to calculate, substracting `lochpos` and `locwidth` from `\paperwidth` to get your new `refwidth`.
- **Width:** You can simply use `locwidth` as you did, perhaps the option `refline=narrow` could be useful for you in addition.

Since you design the template yourself, you don't have to use predefined values, you could set your own.

Example:

```
\documentclass[refline=narrow]{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{yourref}{Z7H88}
\setkomavar{yourmail}{10/28/2011}
\setkomavar{myref}{A124}
\setkomavar{customer}{42}
\setkomavar{invoice}{I-2011-22}
\setkomavar{date}{11/01/2011}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\@setplength{refhpos}{\paperwidth-7cm}
\@setplength{refwidth}{3cm}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Reader}
\opening{Dear reader,}
\closing{Yours Sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Another approach

You could use

```
\setkomavar{location}{...}
```

to use the location field while designing your own reference fields block therein, not using the predefined reference fields. So you don't have to change position and width.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NickSandford So you could click on the arrow and checkmark on the left of the answer for upvoting and accepting ;-)

Comment: It says I need a certain amount of reputation to do that haha, first post and everything :). I'm almost there, and when I am I will. For the second approach, is there somewhere I can view how the current reference line is rendered, so that I can use that as a template for setting the location variable?

Comment: @NickSandford: You can't upvote (click on the arrow) yet, but you can accept (click on the checkmark).

Comment: Ah, righto. Didn't notice that! Thanks.

Comment: @NickSandford: you can see it in `scrlttr2.cls`, look for `\@set@reffield` and related macros in that place of the source code.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, found it, cheers. It looks like you can add your own koma vars to the ref fields line, that's kinda nifty. Thanks for pointing that out for me :).

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. `refwidth` alters the position of the subject. That induces: If you increase `refwidth` to say 6 cm, the subject is above the `addrfield`.

Comment: Short: Add `\@setplength{refaftervskip}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}-2\baselineskip}`
Long: I just dug into the [KOMA manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) and realized what a kludge this solution is ... but also that there is no clean one by modifying the reference line. On p. 362 you can see that this workaround basically replaces the *supplemental area* and that all your content/type area behaves relative to the lower end of the reference line. Hence having few references will inevitably overlap the address window. Therefore enlarge `refaftervskip`.