# Left Justifying the Date with Scrlttr2

Tags: positioning, koma-script, letters

I would like to left justify the date in the KOMA-Script scrlttr2
class so that it aligns with the left margin of the body.  I have no other data in the refline.  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33287/how-to-position-the-reference-fields-line-in-scrlttr2) helped me to get my present workaround, which is as follows:

Shrink the width of the refline field:

```
\@setplength{refwidth}{2.5cm}
```

Manually position the refline field:

```
\@setplength{refhpos}{2.27cm}
```

While this can produce the output I want, when the width of the date
changes, such as at the start of the month (think July->August), I
have to manually edit the variables to get the proper alignment.

Is there a more elegant way within KOMA-Script to left justify the date? If there is not a built-in method: Is there a way to automate the calculation of the widths or lengths when I compile so that justification remains constant regardless of the length of date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, and may be somewhat stupid, but it seemed to work fine with my simple test:

```
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
```

Comment: This does indeed seem to do the trick and certainly beats my manual workaround.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do this (maybe this option wasn't present before) is by setting the `refline=dateleft` option, either as a documentclass option, or in the preamble like this:

```
\KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft}
```

This aligns both the city and the date to the left.

Comment: This option was present since [KOMAScript version 3.09](http://www.komascript.de/release3.09) (January 2011).