# Changing The Date Location On A Letter

Tags: positioning, letters, datetime, scrlttr2

I'm using the document class `scrlttr2` to make a cover letter, but since it's a business letter the date needs to be left-justified and above the address. By using the work-around [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/left-justifying-the-date-with-scrlttr2) I was able to left-justify it, but I can't figure out how to change the position of the date and the justification is matched up the letter's body and not the address section. Since everything else is exactly where I want it to be I would like to not switch to another class, and I was hoping that someone here could help me out.

Here's my sample code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Short Stylish Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (28/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Stefano (http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/63)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% The two fonts used in this template: Adobe Garamond Pro and Gill Sans
% do not come with Windows by default. You will need to download them in
% order to get an output as in the preview PDF. Otherwise, change those 
% fonts to fonts that do come with Windows or comment out the lines to use 
% the default font.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     --
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   --

\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Required to compile in Windows
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
\setsansfont {Cambria} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11.5}{12}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and    leading
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --
%  HEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape Peter Maguire}\\   [5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape My Job \\ My Institution } % Your current job   title


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COVER LETTER CONTENTS
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --

\begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
Biotech Company \\
123 Street Street \\
Washington, CA 12345 
}


\opening{Biotech Company HR Manager,}

\begin{sloppypar}
Main section here 
\\
\end{sloppypar}

Sincerely, \\
Peter Maguire

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   --

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

And this roughly what I want it to look like:

[image]

Anyone more skilled in this stuff have any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes you may have to cheat a little...

Below I set the date as part of the address, leaving the `date` empty:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

%\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
%\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Required to compile in Windows
\usepackage{graphicx}


\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont {Adobe Garamond Pro} % Main document font
%\setsansfont {Cambria} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11.5}{12}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and    leading
%\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
\setkomavar{date}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --
%  HEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{firsthead}{
    \centering
    {%\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}
        \fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape Peter Maguire}\\[5mm]
    \fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape My Job \\ My Institution } % Your current job   title


\begin{document}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % COVER LETTER CONTENTS
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --

    \begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
            \today \par \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
            Biotech Company \\
            123 Street Street \\
            Washington, CA 12345 
        }


        \opening{Biotech Company HR Manager,}

        \begin{sloppypar}
            Main section here \\
        \end{sloppypar}

        Sincerely, \\
        Peter Maguire

        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   --

    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're the best! This is exactly what I was looking for. I hope you have a wonderful rest of your day.